# Scala : cleanest way to recursively parse files checking for multiple strings

Tags: string, file, scala

I want to write a Scala script to recursively process all files in a directory.  For each file I'd like to see if there are any cases where a string occurs at line X and line X - 2.  If a case like that occurs I'd like to stop processing that file, and add that filename to a map of filenames to occurrence counts.  I just started learning Scala today, I've got the file recurse code working, and need some help with the string searching, here's what I have so far:

```
import java.io.File
import scala.io.Source

val s1= "CmdNum = 506"
val s2 = "Data = [0000,]"

def processFile(f: File) {
  val lines = scala.io.Source.fromFile(f).getLines.toArray
  for (i = 0 to lines.length - 1) {
    // want to do string searches here, see if line contains s1 and line two lines above also contains s1
    //println(lines(i))
  }
}

def recursiveListFiles(f: File): Array[File] = {
  val these = f.listFiles
  if (these != null) {
    for (i = 0 to these.length - 1) {
      if (these(i).isFile) {
        processFile(these(i))
      }
    }
    these ++ these.filter(_.isDirectory).flatMap(recursiveListFiles)
  }
  else {
    Array[File]()
  }
}

println(recursiveListFiles(new File(args(0))))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
def processFile(f: File) {
  val src = Source.fromFile(f)
  val hit = src.getLines().sliding(3).exists{ 
    case List(l0, l1, l2) => l0.contains(s1) && l2.contains(s1)
    case _ => false
  }
  src.close
  // do something depending on hit like adding to a Map
}
```

First you don't need to convert to an array, you can preserve the iterator to only read the lines necessary to find a match.

You can use `sliding` to get a derived iterator using a sliding window of 3 lines where you look for the string on line `i` and `i+2`.

`exists` tests whether an element of this sliding iterator satisfy a predicate. The `case` will pattern match the 3 lines from the sliding window element into 3 vals for convenience. *I had to use the REPL to find out what type the sliding was really returning*.

Finally don't forget to close src.

If you need the occurrence count:

```
  val count = src.getLines().sliding(3).filter{ 
    case List(l0, l1, l2) => l0.contains(s1) && l2.contains(s1)
    case _ => false
  }.size
```

You filter the occurrences and then get the size...

*edited for match error on files shorter than 3 lines*

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried it out but an getting an exception when it's processing the files:

Comment: scala.MatchError: List(2010-05-31 17:31:06.015 UTC+0000 INFO [xxx-HostSy
ncThread-Runnable->HostSync-176666318810351] estation.services.timesync.TimeSync
 - Successful time sync with host 'http://www04.xxx.com:80': parsed resp
onse of 1275327066705 into system time of Mon May 31 17:31:06 UTC 2010)
        at Main$$anon$1$$anonfun$1.apply(506.scala:13)
        at Main$$anon$1$$anonfun$1.apply(506.scala:13)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.exists(Iterator.scala:655)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.exists(Iterator.scala:772)

Comment: @fred, I added `case _ => false` to handle short files.

Comment: Arguably, I'd think sliding 3 returning a list with less than 3 elements is a bug.

Comment: Thanks guys, nice job.  This newfangled Scala sure is good at expressing what you want with very few LOC :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative way of doing this:

```
import java.io.File
import scala.io.Source

val s1= "CmdNum = 506"

def filesAt(f: File): Array[File] = if (f.isDirectory) f.listFiles flatMap filesAt else Array(f)

def filterFiles(arr: Array[File]) = arr filter (
    Source
    fromFile _
    getLines ()
    sliding 3
    exists { 
        case List(l1, l2, l3) => List(l1, l3) forall (_ contains s1)
        case _ => false
    }
)

println(filterFiles(filesAt(new File(args(0)))))
```

Though I'll confess I cheated a bit. I actually had to write this instead of `Source fromFile _`:

```
Source.fromFile(_)(scala.io.Codec.ISO8859)
```

Because, otherwise, Scala would barf on invalid UTF-8 encodings.

Answer (score 1):

It needs refining to deal with files shorter than 3 lines, but at a first stab I'd try something like this:

```
def checkFile(file: File) = {
  val lines = ...
  (lines zip lines.tail.tail) exists { _1 = _2 }
}
```

Then

```
val files = ...
val validFiles = files filter { checkFile }
```

Apologies for being so brief, I'm answering on my mobile...

Comment: Ah files having less than 3 lines, that explains the match error in my answer :)